# How to trigger external URL popup in the routerlink

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I have Angular 4 application using Angular router. I have hyperlink that opens a new component's dialog box. I already know how to open modal dialog from a function.

**component.html**

```
<p-dialog header="New Activity" width="350" 
    [(visible)]="displayDialog" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" 
    [modal]="true">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="status">
        <span translate>Status</span>
    </label>
    <div>
       <input pInputText readonly formControlName="Status" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am triggering the function inside the form by using the below function

**component.ts**

```
showDialogToAdd() {
    this.displayDialog = true;
}
```

Now i need to call the page with dialog box open from another component

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" [routerLink]="['../activities', {displayDialog: 'true'}]" class="wa-btn">
    <i class="icon ic-sm icon-add"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subscribe for query params in `ngOnInit()` as:

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.displayDialog = params['displayDialog'] || false;
});
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['activities']" [queryParams]="{ displayDialog: true }" class="wa-btn">
   <i class="icon ic-sm icon-add"></i>
</a>
```